# Sort ArrayList<Object> by date that contains two different Object Classes

Tags: java, android

I have two Model classes that I am adding to ArrayList items and both of the model classes have a getDate() and I want to sort the list by date. I have been going at it for a while but can't seem to get it.

```
    ArrayList<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<LiftDate> liftDates = LiftDateHandler.get(getActivity()).getDate();
    ArrayList<OneRepMax> oneRepMaxes = OneRepMaxHandler.get(getActivity()).getORM();
    items.addAll(liftDates);
    items.addAll(oneRepMaxes);
```

Both LiftDate.class and OneRepMax.class contain:

```
public Date getDate() {
    return mDate;
}
```

How do I sort the ArrayList items based on the two Objects getDate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Define a common `interface` that `LiftDate` and `OneRepMax` both implement. This interface should include `getDate()`. I'll use `Snicklefritz` as the name of this interface in this answer; you should choose something more meaningful for your app.

Step #2: Have `items` be an `ArrayList<Snicklefritz>`.

Step #3: Implement a `Comparator<Snicklefritz>` that performs your date comparison using `getDate()`.

Step #4: [Use `Collections.sort()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29) to sort the `ArrayList` using your `Comparator`.